# Triggers in Blend Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2022, blend

I want to add animation that starts immediately when the window opens, but I have Microsoft Blend 2022 which does not have triggers option so I have to write in code how do I want my animation to start, but I am not sure how to start it immediately.

I have tried to find a way through some videos but nobody explains how to make the animation start immediately when the window opens.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your Window's XAML trigger under `Window.Triggers`, based on `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event,  without specifying `SourceName` property (it would be window itself). That's what Blend does (afaik).

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.YourWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="YourWindowTitle" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
         <Storyboard x:Key="YourStoryboard">
             <!-- Storyboard animations -->
         </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <!-- This one triggers after Window appears -->
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"> 
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource YourStoryboard}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Window content -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```